# JAXB dependency conflict?

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, docx4j

I faced an error using docx4j and probably found, why it happens:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: JAXB: Can't instantiate JAXB Reference Implementation
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.jaxb.ri.NamespacePrefixMapper]
```

In my project I use docx4j-JAXB-Internal v.8.1.2 + docx4j-export-fo v.8.1.2 (by Maven)

I also use Hibernate (hibernate-core-5.4.2)
As you can see in their POM, dependencies contains:

1. javax.xml.bind -> jaxb-api v.2.3.1
2. org.glassfish.jaxb -> jaxb-runtime v.2.3.1

So, when I come to `NamespacePrefixMapperUtils::getPrefixMapper`,

it tries to find "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl",

- refers to docx4j-JAXB-Internal,

but there I get "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl"

- refers to hibernate -> glassfish -> jaxb-runtime

I think there's a dependency conflict, how can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this:

in folder

```
resources/META-INF/services
```

I've created file with name *javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext*

and then I've put inside this string:

*com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory*

the default context factory, that was overwritten
And so it's a profit

Comment: GIven Hibernate's deps, did you try using https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl/8.1.2/jar instead of docx4j-JAXB-Internal v.8.1.2?

Comment: @JasonPlutext I didn't, because the first comment in docx4j-Getting-started (in the part about Maven) sais:
To use docx4j 8.0.0, add one and only one of the following to your project:
<!-- use the JAXB shipped in Java 8 -->
... docx4j-JAXB-Internal ..., so I use java8 and I understand this comment (I've also seen similar comments on web) to use JAXB-Internal